# trouble with uiscrollview paging in iOS 6 using storyboard

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, paging

I have a very strange problem. I'm using this tutorial: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/ in order to make an `uiscrollview` paging. But it seems just not to work in iOS 6 when I try to implement it in storyboard. I just copied the code and made all the necessary steps. But it still doesn't work. `UIScrollView` just refuses to show anything. But the point is, that it worked perfectly before I updated my Xcode to the latest version. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Maybe I forgot something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to uncheck use AutoLayout under "File inspector"